# Databricks spark permission denied (Errno 13) on local disk during ETL

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, permissions, databricks

We have a custom ETL pipeline running as a python module on a Databricks cluster. At one point in this ETL pipeline we have to create a spark dataframe from multiple pandas dataframes. We do this with:

```
full_data = pd.concat(
                [self.drift_data.null_proportions,
                self.drift_data.categorical,
                self.drift_data.numeric]
                )

full_data_schema = StructType([ StructField("export_date", TimestampType(), True)\
                                       ,StructField("source", StringType(), True)\
                                       ,StructField("col", StringType(), True)\
                                       ,StructField("col_type", StringType(), True)\
                                       ,StructField("metric", StringType(), True)\
                                       ,StructField("category_value", StringType(), True)\
                                       ,StructField("val", DoubleType(), True)\
                                       ,StructField("threshold", DoubleType(), True)])

full_data_spark = self.spark_session.createDataFrame(full_data,schema=full_data_schema)
```

Most of the times we run this code on our cluster, we have no problems. However, sometimes when we run this code we get the following error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/local_disk0/spark-6c598094-676d-4a43-bce1-b99b4bf36545/trustedTemp-254afa1a-ad7a-44b5-8992-dae14175fa3f/tmpma4wfpoy'
```

There does not seem to be any logical reason when this error pops up. We run the code on a high concurrency cluster with multiple user credential passthrough enabled. I have never seen this error arise when running on a standard cluster.

The error arise in the createDataframe line:

```
/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prm/drift_monitor/DriftMonitor.py in calculate_drift_data(self, date, source, dataframe)
    343                                        ,StructField("threshold", DoubleType(), True)])
    344 
--> 345         full_data_spark = self.spark_session.createDataFrame(full_data,schema=full_data_schema)
    346 
    347         #replace NaNs and nans from pandas to Spark NULLs

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    718         if has_pandas and isinstance(data, pandas.DataFrame):
    719             # Create a DataFrame from pandas DataFrame.
--> 720             return super(SparkSession, self).createDataFrame(
    721                 data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    722         return self._create_dataframe(data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
```

I assume it has something to do with Pandas and permissions and the driver node but I can't seem to find anything helpful. Also the fact that it only happens (seemingly) at random has me left clueless.

Full error stack:

```
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-649024245350800> in <module>
      1 prm = PRMP('dev')
----> 2 prm.run_platform()

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prm/PRMP.py in run_platform(self, disable_date_check, perform_dropout_check)
     50                          ,wrapped_init=True)
     51         for source in ['des', 'pop_prm_rem', 'pop_prm_pr']:
---> 52             dm.perform(source=source)
     53 
     54         logger.info('finished PRM Platform run')

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prm/drift_monitor/DriftMonitor.py in perform(self, source)
     88 
     89             logger.info(f'starting metric calculation')
---> 90             self.calculate_drift_data(date=latest_export, source=source, dataframe=df)
     91             logger.info(f'finished metric calculation')
     92 

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prm/drift_monitor/DriftMonitor.py in calculate_drift_data(self, date, source, dataframe)
    343                                        ,StructField("threshold", DoubleType(), True)])
    344 
--> 345         full_data_spark = self.spark_session.createDataFrame(full_data,schema=full_data_schema)
    346 
    347         #replace NaNs and nans from pandas to Spark NULLs

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    718         if has_pandas and isinstance(data, pandas.DataFrame):
    719             # Create a DataFrame from pandas DataFrame.
--> 720             return super(SparkSession, self).createDataFrame(
    721                 data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    722         return self._create_dataframe(data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/pandas/conversion.py in createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    309                     raise
    310         data = self._convert_from_pandas(data, schema, timezone)
--> 311         return self._create_dataframe(data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    312 
    313     def _convert_from_pandas(self, pdf, schema, timezone):

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in _create_dataframe(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    747                 self._jvm.PythonSecurityUtils.SPARK_PYTHON_TO_JVM_TRUSTED_DATA_TRANSFER_ENABLED()) \
    748                 and not isinstance(data, RDD):
--> 749             jdf, schema = self._createFromLocalTrusted(map(prepare, data), schema)
    750         else:
    751             if isinstance(data, RDD):

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in _createFromLocalTrusted(self, data, schema)
    560         # create the serializer as we do in self._sc.parallelize
    561         serializer = self._sc.init_batched_serializer(data)
--> 562         temp_data_path = self._write_to_trusted_path(data, serializer)
    563 
    564         return self._jsparkSession.createDataFrameFromTrustedPath(temp_data_path, schema.json()), \

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in _write_to_trusted_path(self, data, serializer)
    541         temp_dir = self._jsparkSession.getTrustedPath()
    542         # Create the temp file to dump data, this file would be deleted by the createDF call
--> 543         temp_file = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, dir=temp_dir)
    544 
    545         # Serialize to the trusted path, still reclaim the handler if exception happens in dump

/usr/lib/python3.8/tempfile.py in NamedTemporaryFile(mode, buffering, encoding, newline, suffix, prefix, dir, delete, errors)
    677         flags |= _os.O_TEMPORARY
    678 
--> 679     (fd, name) = _mkstemp_inner(dir, prefix, suffix, flags, output_type)
    680     try:
    681         file = _io.open(fd, mode, buffering=buffering,

/usr/lib/python3.8/tempfile.py in _mkstemp_inner(dir, pre, suf, flags, output_type)
    387         _sys.audit("tempfile.mkstemp", file)
    388         try:
--> 389             fd = _os.open(file, flags, 0o600)
    390         except FileExistsError:
    391             continue    # try again

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/local_disk0/spark-6c598094-676d-4a43-bce1-b99b4bf36545/trustedTemp-254afa1a-ad7a-44b5-8992-dae14175fa3f/tmpma4wfpoy'
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your databricks runtime to be version 7.5+, in which databricks creates per notebook home directory on the high concurrency clusters, and you'll not have the permission issue.

Refer [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/9809) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I forgot to mention that we are running on DBR 9.1 LTS so this can not be the problem.

Comment: @MatthijsvanKesteren did you end up resolving this? i'm getting the same error and can't find a fix, i'm also on the same runtime

Comment: @MatthijsvanKesteren - same here. Its 2024 and I also got the same error on one of our process. Were you able to resolve this? thanks!